# Automating 'Eclipse Plugin' testing with Jubula and Maven

Tags: eclipse, testing, maven, plugins, jubula

I need to Automate the Eclipse Plugin UI tests.

Jubula is a UI testing automation.
The plugins are built using Maven (3.0 version)

Does anybody know to integrate them (Jubula and Maven) and automate the testing 
process..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is Jubula a requirement or can you use other frameworks like SWTBot?

Comment: Anyway SWTBot can be integrated easily as it supports 'Headless testing' and it is similar to JUnit... I specifically want to find out an answer about Jubula-Maven integration

Answer (score 0):

This question may have already been answered in the Jubula forum:

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/365105/